# How do I stop drupal from creating a different consolidated CSS file for every node type?

Tags: css, drupal-6

I have a fairly large Drupal 6 site with different modules enabled for different node/page types which is resulting in a different CSS file for each page type after the CSS has been consolidated. I understand the logic of not wanting to load css for every module, but is there a method for loading sitewide css into one file so that we can utilize the caching benefits of CSS?

Homepage:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/site-files/example.com/files/css/css_1f2e88da1acf78556ee565984845d7cd.css" /></code>
```

Article:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/site-files/example.com/files/css/css_1786ec41724511f6c0984222b790dca6.css" />
```

Category:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/site-files/example.com/files/css/css_b7f516c6ab4921929598cfd377ce4523.css" />
```

Video:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/site-files/example.com/files/css/css_a702453ef81af3318ad63a194280100e.css" />
```

There must be some logic in making these all one file when you consider that the difference between them is minimal.

Cheers, Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question...

As always with Drupal, someone's already been there and done that, and here it is:

http://drupal.org/project/advagg

A little extra research into the benefits of first page load time vs a larger site side cached file, etc. has been very insightful.